# Не осложняет ли Spring Dependency Inversion Principle?

Tags: java, spring

Если понимать, что принцип инверсий зависимостей подразумевает, что наиболее гибкими системами являются те, где в **ИСХОДНОМ** коде зависимости направлены на абстракции, а не конкретные реализации, то не мешает ли следовать этому принципу Спринг. Ведь использование интерфейсов сделано довольно сложно, тебе нужно либо перебирать все реализации интерфейсов и искать подходящий, что сложно, либо использовать @Qualified, что делает **ИСХОДНЫЙ** код зависимым на реализацию, а не абстракцию.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113787/discussion-on-question-by-kaylil-01----spring-dependency-inversion).

Answer (score 0):

DI подразумевает, что разные аспекты кода не зависимы друг от друга, что и реализует Spring с помощью @Bean @Component @Autowired, это действительно удобно, ведь программист не задумывается о кол-ве объектов, и то как они между собой взаимодействуют, так как на это, на себя берет Spring Context.

Comment: Dependency Injection и Dependency Inversion Principle разные вещи, инжекшн - это реализация IOC, чем и занимается спринг, DIP же про композицию классов и их отношения и тут спринг ничего не делает, все остаётся на вас.